# How to spot or match the specific sector of the DVD disc in the movie?

Tags: video, dvd, sectors

[image: VSO Inspector Result]

I've been checking the condition of DVD discs with VSO Inspector. 
Most of time, it doesn't show any errors on the discs. However, when there's an error on a disc, sometimes it shows that there's an error in the beginning of the sectors and sometimes at the end of the sectors.

My question is, how can I find these sectors in the movie? As you can see in the attached photo, there's a reading error starting from the **sector 29152** in total of  **3782560 Sectors** (7.21 GB). Would it be beginning of the movie or at the end of the movie? How can find the exact time of the sector in the movie? I would like to check what's actually happening in the movie at a specific time which matches to the failed sector.

Comment: Since fragmentation does not exist on optical drives, and the process of writing the disk in the first place removed fragmentation of the file, the file would have been written in continuous sectors on the disk.  So if you have detected an error in a given sector, all you would need to know is the size of each sector ( total size of file/number of sectors ) to determine an estimated location within the file.

Comment: But that would give a *byte* offset into the file, and the question is asking for a ***time*** offset.